# Delete[] operator makes *.exe trigger a breakpoint and wntdll.pdb not loaded to appear

Tags: c++, delete-operator

`Delete[]fName` in `decode()` causes this error, `delete` in `encode()` works fine. Without that `delete`, each new call of `decode()` results in 1 more MB wasted, which is expected, buy why adding `delete` causes crash there, but not in `encode()` ? `MAX_STRING_LENGTH` constant is `1048576` (1 MB of chars)

```
  void encode()
    {
        char* usrChars = new char[MAX_STRING_LENGTH];
        memset(usrChars, 0, MAX_STRING_LENGTH);
        cin.get();
        cin.getline(usrChars, MAX_STRING_LENGTH);
        ofstream f("E:/fc/enc_test.txt");
        //do stuff
        f.close();
        delete[]usrChars; //works fine
        decode();
        cout << endl;
    }
    void decode()
    {
        char* fName = new char[MAX_STRING_LENGTH];
        memset(fName, 0, MAX_STRING_LENGTH);    
        fName = "e:/fc/enc_test.txt";
        ifstream f(fName);  
        delete[]fName; //causes crash
        //do stuff
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fName = "e:/fc/enc_test.txt";` causes `fName` to point to the location where the string literal `"e:/fc/enc_test.txt"` is stored. You then try to delete *that* location which was not allocated with `new`. You need to use `std::strcpy` to copy a c string. You can save yourself quite a bit of headache by using `std::string` instead.

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

void decode()
{
    std::string fName = "e:/fc/enc_test.txt";
    std::ifstream f(fName);
    // do stuff (no delete required for fName)
}
```

Comment: trying to cin std::string with spaces makes everything go haywire, cin.getline only accepts chars

Comment: @AdmiralMyxtaR If you make `usrChars` an `std::string` you can use `std::getline(std::cin, usrChars);` for your input. [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) can read full lines into an `std::string`.

Answer (score 5):

The reason `decode` crashes and `encode` does not is because you are trying to delete a pointer that was not allocated with `new`.  You did allocate with `new` to begin with but when you do `fName = "e:/fc/enc_test.txt";` you change `fname` to point to a string literal instead of the memory you originally allocated.  Trying to delete it after that is why you crash.

---

You should turn up the warnings on your compiler as

```
fName = "e:/fc/enc_test.txt";
```

Should be an error since `"e:/fc/enc_test.txt"` has the type `const char[]` and you should not be able to assign it to a `char*`.